# User Defined Functions option issue

Tags: cassandra

I'm using `Cassandra 3.6` on `CentOS 7.2.1511`, and I want to use `user-defined functions` but I got this error :

`InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="User-defined functions are disabled in cassandra.yaml - set enable_user_defined_functions=true to enable`

I turned on this option in each node on `cassandra.yaml` and restart them with `sudo cassandra service restart` but I still get this error :(

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! I just restarted my 3 VMs and now it works :)